# unable to run a python script without specifying full path

Tags: python, linux

Hi I am trying to run a python script directly from terminal. For this I have added the directory which contains the code to my environment PATH variable. However I am able to run when I specify full path but not when I just call the script.

```
(base) DS:~ $ /home/user_abc/my_codes/status.py
Everything is ok!
(base) DS:~ $ echo $PATH
/home/user_abc/anaconda3/bin:/home/user_abc/mycodes:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
(base) DS:~ $ status.py
-bash: status.py: command not found
(base) DS:~ $ /status.py
-bash: /status.py: No such file or directory
(base) DS:~ $ ./status.py
-bash: ./status.py: No such file or directory
(base) DS:~ $
```

My shebang looks lie this.

```
#!/home/user_abc/anaconda3/bin/python3


(base) DS:~ $ python3 status.py
python3: can't open file status.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
(base) DS:~ $ python status.py
python: can't open file 'status.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
(base) DS:~ $
```

While I don't want python and simply want to call the script as any other command.

Comment: You can run the script py useing `python3` as a prefix so you can use `python3 scriptname.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PATH doesn't include the path of your script.

You have mentioned `/home/user_abc/mycodes` in your path but the location of python script is under `/home/user_abc/my_codes/`

Run this command to fix the issue.

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/user_abc/my_codes
$ status.py
```

Comment: How will just writing status.py execute the file?

Comment: wow it boils down to me making a silly mistake. Thanks for pointing. I will accept this answer

Comment: @Divyeesh look like you are a newbie like me. But this is how experienced people are doing:)

Answer (score 1):

Your PATH seems wrong.

`/home/user_abc/mycodes` should be `/home/user_abc/my_codes`.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to at least mention the relative path like this:

```
$ python my_codes/status.py
```

Also to learn more about relative paths refer here: [link](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/supplement/pathnames-explained-absolute-relative-unc-and-url.htm)

You need to mention python because since it is not an executable, that is, it is just a script, we need to mention which interpreter we want to execute it.